# Complex query in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I  have two tables `reports` and `holidays`.

`reports`: `(username varchar(30),activity varchar(30),hours int(3),report_date date)`

`holidays`: `(holiday_name varchar(30), holiday_date date)`

`select * from reports`  gives

```
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
| username |  activity |  hours  |   date     |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
| prasoon  |   testing |    3    | 2009-01-01 |
| prasoon  |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-03 |
| gautam   |   coding  |    1    | 2009-01-05 |  
| prasoon  |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-06 |
| prasoon  |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-10 |
| gautam   |   coding  |    4    | 2009-01-10 |
+----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

`select * from holidays` gives

```
+--------------+---------------+  
| holiday_name |  holiday_date |
+--------------+---------------+ 
| Diwali       |   2009-01-02  |
| Holi         |   2009-01-05  |  
+--------------+---------------+
```

When I used the following query

```
 SELECT dates.date AS date,
  CASE 
    WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(reports.activity, 'Absent') 
    WHEN holiday_name IS NOT NULL and reports.activity IS NOT NULL THEN  reports.activity
  ELSE ''
    END 
  AS activity,
  CASE WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(reports.hours, 'Absent')
    WHEN holiday_name IS NOT NULL and reports.hours IS NOT NULL THEN reports.hours
    ELSE ''
    END 
  AS hours,
  CASE 
    WHEN holiday_name IS NULL THEN COALESCE(holidays.holiday_name, '')
    ELSE holidays.holiday_name
    END 
  AS holiday_name
  FROM dates 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN reports ON dates.date = reports.date 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN holidays ON dates.date = holidays.holiday_date
  where reports.username='gautam' and dates.date>='2009-01-01' and dates.date<='2009-01-10';
```

I got the following output

```
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |  date    |  activity |  hours  |   holiday  |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |2009-01-05|   coding  |    1    |   Holi     |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-10|   coding  |    4    |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

but I expected this

```
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |  date    |  activity |  hours  |   holiday  |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+  
   |2009-01-01|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-02|           |         | Diwali     |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-03|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-04|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-05|  Coding   |   1     | Holi       |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-06|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-07|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-08|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-09|  Absent   | Absent  |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
   |2009-01-10|  Coding   |   4     |            |
   +----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

How can I modify the above query to get the desired output(for a particular user (gautam in this case))?

**EDIT**

I also have a table `dates(date date)` which contains all the dates between `2009-01-01` to `2020-12-31`

Comment: You also have a third table `dates`. Now I can probably guess the table structure and contents of this table, but for completeness you probably should add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your WHERE clauses inside the JOIN clauses. The only thing I've changed is the last couple of lines:

```
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN reports ON dates.date = reports.date
AND reports.username='gautam'
LEFT JOIN holidays ON dates.date = holidays.holiday_date
AND dates.date >= '2009-01-01'
AND dates.date <= '2009-01-10'
```

You accepted the answer above, but further testing showed that although it works for you, it didn't work for me. Here is something that works for me:

```
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN reports ON dates.date = reports.date
AND reports.username='gautam'
LEFT JOIN holidays ON dates.date = holidays.holiday_date
WHERE dates.date >= '2009-01-01'
AND dates.date <= '2009-01-10'
```

Comment: @Satish: Despite that you had accepted my answer, I think my original answer didn't quite do what you wanted so I've updated it with a correction. If you think the update is wrong I can roll back to the answer you accepted.

Comment: @Mark Byers:Roll back your answer actually i was mistaken taking the range of date so i got the absurd result but your previous answer has worked.

Comment: CASE and COALESCE are used incorrectly here. The second WHEN is totally unnecessary, because COALESCE(reports.hours, 'Absent') will return reports.hours if it's not null. For the same reason, you don't need a case statement at all for holiday_name.

Comment: @Satish: OK I've reverted the answer... but when I test this locally it doesn't work so I have no idea why it works for you.

Comment: @Satish: Someone downvoted my answer, which is not surpising since it is clearly wrong when i test locally, despite it apparently working for you. I have decided to compromise: I'm going to leave the answer you accepted visible AND the answer that I believe is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer will work great, but you are doing something that's very poor practice - **you're using SQL to format your information**. This is bad! You should be using it only to retrieve your information, and then format it with HTML or whatever you're pulling the data into. Your select should be a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM reports WHERE username='guatam'
 AND date>='2009-01-01' AND date<='2009-01-9'
```

And a separate one for the holidays, if you need it:

```
SELECT * from holidays
```

And then use that information as you need.

Comment: I disagree - SQL will scale a lot better than application code as the resultset gets larger.  And secondly - the question is about returning correct results, not formatting.

Comment: Most of the query in the question is formatting - using COALESCE to return empty space instead of NULL, and having a separate dates table so that there's a line for every date. Even if it scales better, just pulling the information allows him to change the way the information is displayed on the front end without messing with queries. That's why it's considered bad practice.